# Is it forbidden to approach a random girl in the street in order to get to know her?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam

I think i only know few girls in my social circle, and i want to expand that by knowing other girls outside my social circle. I don't want to be single forever, and i don't want to break Islam rules either, that's why i'm here asking for your opinion.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's your intentions that matter. If you're approaching the girl for a casual relationship that involves getting intimate with each other before marriage, then it's wrong in the eyes of Allah.

I do believe your consciousness should be answer to this question

Answer (score -1):

(i see that "to get to know" means "to start to be familiar with someone or something").

i think, your intention ("and i want to expand that by knowing other girls outside my social circle") is not respectful enough "to get to know" a girl. i think, you should "get to know" a girl only when you intent to marry.

but, what if i modify your idea and think that you do not want to "get to know", but you say only about taking contacts (phone etc) of a girl with intention to "get to know" her in future when you want to marry someone, and you have no idea whom you want to get to know better for that. in that case, i think, it is quite meaningless, because many years can pass before you intent to marry, and you probably can get contacts of many girls at that time, and even getting a contact of an unknown girl is quite hard and nervous act, and it is quite unlikely that you will contact with her after many years, and even more unlikely that you marry her.

i cannot support my opinion with hadithes, i do not know them, and i am lazy to search them for now. my opinion is based on meaning of "marriage". if you are not married to a girl, which is not your sister or daughter etc, you should not contact with her without respectful reason.

Answer (score -1):

-Well, No bad to get to know... She's a "**Muslim**" girl like you... So, I think it's okay for 2 peoples belong to the same religion to get to know as a "**Brothers**" & "**Sisters**" in religion.

-But, If you intend to hurt her by exploiting her feelings/emotions or manipulating her feelings/emotions... Or, Hurting her with enjoying her body by looking at it or taking photos... Then, It's forbidden... & Also, Anything such is forbidden.

-As long as it's a (respectful & kind) relationship between 2 peoples of the same religion... Then, No problem.

**Greetings**!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].